# OpenLayers: embedding map in asp .net webpage

Tags: javascript, asp.net, maps, openlayers, openstreetmap

I have requirement to show place on map using lat and long on open street map with markers. I I have tried some code after searching in Google. But showing nothing. I am providing my code and some example link which i have tried.

```
<head runat="server">
  <title>OpenLayers Simplest Example</title>
  <script src="OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="osm-marker-popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <h1 id="title">
     OSM with Marker and Popup</h1>
     <p id="shortdesc">
       Demonstrate use of an OSM layer with a marker and a popup.
     </p>
     <div id="tags">
        openstreetmap osm marker popup
     </div>
     <div id="map">
     </div>
     <div id="docs">
        <p>
            A common use case for OpenLayers is to display a marker at a location on the map,
            and add some information in a popup. It is also easy to add a tooltip with a short
            description. See the <a href="osm-marker-popup.js" target="_blank">osm-marker-popup.js
            source</a> to see how this is done.
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Code of osm-marker-popup.js

```
var map;
function init() {

// The overlay layer for our marker, with a simple diamond as symbol
var overlay = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('Overlay', {
    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
        externalGraphic: '../img/marker.png',
        graphicWidth: 20, graphicHeight: 24, graphicYOffset: -24,
        title: '${tooltip}'
    })
});

// The location of our marker and popup. We usually think in geographic
// coordinates ('EPSG:4326'), but the map is projected ('EPSG:3857').
var myLocation = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(10.2, 48.9)
    .transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

// We add the marker with a tooltip text to the overlay
overlay.addFeatures([
    new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(myLocation, { tooltip: 'OpenLayers' })
]);

// A popup with some information about our location
var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("Popup",
    myLocation.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(), null,
    '<a target="_blank" href="http://openlayers.org/">We</a> ' +
    'could be here.<br>Or elsewhere.', null,
    true // <-- true if we want a close (X) button, false otherwise
);

// Finally we create the map
map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map", projection: "EPSG:3857",
    layers: [new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(), overlay],
    center: myLocation.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(), zoom: 15
});
// and add the popup to it.
  map.addPopup(popup);
}
```

Links.
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Simple_Example
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Openlayers_POI_layer_example
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Marker

Comment: Where are you creating your OpenLayers *map*? You are missing the most important code of the examples. Just including OpenLayers.js won't be enough.

Comment: @scai please tell what i have missed.

Comment: You missed creating a *map* via `new OpenLayers.Map()`, adding a *layer* and so on. Please look at the examples again.

Comment: @scai it is in osm-marker-popup.js. Full script function in this js file.

Comment: So how should anybody be able to help you if you won't show us your code? And did you already checked your browser's error console?

Comment: @scai i have posted osm-marker-popup.js code. check it..

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 <script src="OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to

```
 <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
```